# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded NEXTJS

Tags: server, range, action, next.js13, stack-size

I'm still a beginner in Nextjs
I get range error when i try to fetch products from database,
ihave the same exact code for categories with no problem at all...

this my nextjs server action:

```
export async function getProducts() {
try {
connectToDB();
return await Product.find({});
} catch (error: any) {
throw new Error(`Failed to catch products : ${error.message}`);
}
}
```

this is from my client side:

```
const getAllProducts = async () => {
try {
  const response = await getProducts();
  console.log('response: ', response);
  setProducts(response);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
} useEffect(() => {
getAllProducts()}, []);
```

can someone tell me whats wrong here i see no loops and i have the same exact code literally for categories section no problems at all

Comment: the useEffect can cause you to infinite loop which throw that error

Comment: even if i deleted the useeffect and called getAllproducts function from another function  it causes the same error

Comment: how does the connectToDB looks like?

Comment: `let isConnected = false; 

export const connectToDB = async () => {
  mongoose.set("strictQuery", true);

  if (!process.env.MONGODB_URL) return console.log("Missing MongoDB URL");

  if (isConnected) {
    console.log("MongoDB connection already established");
    return;
  }

  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL);
    isConnected = true; 
    console.log("MongoDB connected");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};`

Answer (score 3):

I had a same problem.
Nextjs seems to have problems sending your object that you get back from the database to a client component.

A working workaround that helped me was the following:

In the server action stringify your result:

```
connectToDB();
const products = await Product.find({})
return JSON.stringify(products);
```

And than at the client side parse the string back to json.

```
const response = await getProducts();
responseJson = JSON.parse(response)
console.log('response: ', responseJson);
```

I know this can have several problems since a string is now being sent. But it currently works for me.
However, the solution is not perfect and should not always be used.

Answer (score 1):

Within Nextjs 13/14, the "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error usually comes from a mismatch between server and client components.

In this case, it seems your server action likely isn't returning a plain object (which is a requirement), and can throw this error.

Another common cause of this error is rendering a server component as a child of a client component.